# Is there a way to replace INDIRECT in this formula? Would like to put something lighter than INDIRECT (volatile function)

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is my formula:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX($H:$J,,MATCH(Q$6,$H$3:$J$3,0)),INDIRECT($U$22),$O$3,INDIRECT($U$23),$O$4)
```

It's just a SUMIFS using INDEX MATCH to dynamically look for the column (Sum_Range), and then I have an INDIRECT to indicate which column out of a set of possible columns need to be used as (Criteria_Range), depending on some previous filters - dropdown list.

Thanks in advance! And any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: its potentially possible.  Some sample data would go a long way to showing you potential alternatives

Comment: Yes,, it's possible but we need some sample data to fix the issue !

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you certainly can. However... the devil is in the details.

First, and most important, is WHY are those two values put into the formula with `INDIRECT()`? If it is because a user directly inputs information into the cells referenced, then you would have to provide for that. For example, you might have different cells, somewhere in the spreadsheet, that contain the `INDIRECT()`'s used here and then this formula could reference THOSE cells so the user interaction goes on as always, but this formula loses the `INDIRECT()`'s. Or, better really, than some out-of-the-way cell, you could put them into `Named Ranges`.

Not that it looks like a problem here, but if you want to replace them because of calculation load, this would not solve that. Other approaches would depend on the user input and how readily one can use it in other functions to build references that this formula can use. The best function is also volatile, which makes sense, and so isn't much of a replacement if calculation load is the important factor.

Second, if there is no user input that matters, then you are home free. No user input directly affecting them means that whatever string is in those two cells is being created from just whatever is in the spreadsheet, change though it might. So you can bring THOSE formulas into this one in place of the two `INDIRECT()`'s. Easy-peasey. There ARE some pitfalls, mostly with the way `Spill-`ing works, and doesn't, in formulas, but my bet is this isn't super brandnew, so that last wouldn't be an issue. (Some things generated in the `Spill` environment can be referenced by another formula and work beautifully, but if inserted into a formula, as part of it, like I mentioned a couple sentences ago, fail. Some functions will too, but I wager not here.

Third, do other places in the spreadsheet depend upon the cells the functions reference? If so (and you need to know before starting!), any changes have to be made in a way that works for them as well. Might be as simple as copying those referenced cells' formulas into all the cell formulas affected, not just this one's formula. Or it could be more complex, but probably no more so than combining the first and second paths.

So yes, you can almost certainly replace them, one way or another, and without too much trouble.

However, two less likely problem areas also need mentioned. First is VBA. If there are macros that affect ANY aspect of this, you would need to carefully consider any changes. The second is `FORMULATEXT()`:  if there is any chance any other formulas in the spreadsheet use that function to get the text in the formula and make use of it, then you'd need to consider that impact when making changes. Both pretty unlikely. The third unlikely issue would be other spreadsheets referencing the affected cells, and not being able to handle the easiest changes.